# Sphinx search doesn't stop nor correctly update

Tags: command-line, debian, sphinx

I have problems running sphinx search on my debian Wheezy server.

Currently, there are 2 searchd ports running

```
root@ns243216:~# netstat -tlpn | grep search
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11266/searchd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9312            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11266/searchd
```

**First Problem**
When I want to execute this

```
sudo /usr/bin/indexer -c /etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf beta_jobs --rotate
```

It gives me this :

```
Sphinx 2.2.10-id64-release (2c212e0)
Copyright (c) 2001-2015, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2015, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf'...
indexing index 'beta_jobs'...
collected 6 docs, 0.0 MB
collected 0 attr values
sorted 0.0 Mvalues, 100.0% done
sorted 0.0 Mhits, 100.0% done
total 6 docs, 867 bytes
total 0.046 sec, 18747 bytes/sec, 129.73 docs/sec
total 6 reads, 0.000 sec, 0.4 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
total 12 writes, 0.000 sec, 0.9 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
WARNING: failed to scanf pid from pid_file '/usr/local/sphinx/var/log/searchd/searchd.pid'.
WARNING: indices NOT rotated.
```

2 warnings I can't remove...

**Second Problem**: And when I want to stop my searchd with *searchd --stop*, it tells me this :

```
Sphinx 2.2.10-id64-release (2c212e0)
Copyright (c) 2001-2015, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2015, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf'...
FATAL: stop: failed to read valid pid from '/usr/local/sphinx/var/log/searchd/searchd.pid'
```

I tried setting chmod 755 to everything inside */usr/local/sphinx/var/log/searchd/*, still doesn't work.

My sphinx.conf is here [Sphinx.conf on gist](https://gist.github.com/BabyAzerty/0af82262248e4a179938)

**EDIT** (answer to @aeryaguzov comment)

```
root@ns213646:~# sudo cat /usr/local/sphinx/var/log/searchd/searchd.pid
root@ns213646:~# ps aux | grep searchd
root     11265  0.0  0.0  79692  1228 ?        S    Nov30   0:00 /usr/bin/searchd
root     11266  0.1  0.0  91404  4696 ?        Sl   Nov30  26:54 /usr/bin/searchd
root     22783  0.0  0.0   8292   632 pts/1    S+   15:32   0:00 grep searchd
```

Comment: The problem is with your pid file, so **cat /usr/local/sphinx/var/log/searchd/searchd.pid** and check real pid from **ps aux | grep searchd**

Comment: @aeryaguzov I just edited my question. I checked the searchd.pid with sudo nano too, it is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay it appears that for some unknown reasons the searchd.pid was badly created by searchd (which is running). So I decided to delete the search.pid and to `kill` searchd. Then I re-indexed and started searchd with no problems.